# How to migrate a sub-domain from a shared hosting cpanel to a VPS cpanel

Tags: migration, hosting, cpanel, shared-hosting

My shared hosting structure is as such that allows we to host up to 5 domain under same account which turns out to be as:
    /home/MainDomain/public_html/domian1/
    /home/MainDomain/public_html/domian2/
    /home/MainDomain/public_html/domian3/
etc...

I want to migrate domain1 to a newly purchased VPS hosting company which they have provided me with WHM/cpanel.
If I use the Backup utility from the old shared hosting, it will backup everything (meaning other domains too).
My question is how do I migrate domain1 with all its DBs, cron jobs, and emails to my new VPS account.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you WHM access or only cPanel access?

Comment: I have access to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a functionality in WHM (WHM 64+ versions I believe) that allows you to to convert an addon domain inside a cPanel account into an invidiual cPanel account.

Since you have multiple domains on the same account and I suppose you have websites for those domains as well, then those domains are added as "addon domains" into your cPanel account. So use that WHM convertor tool, convert the desired domain from that cPanel account as a new invidiual cPanel account.

Then create a full cPanel backup for that account. You can do that either from the cPanel web interface or command line (ssh shell).  Once you have the full backup file you can copy it to the new server and restore it from the command line or you can use the WHM transfer tool to transfer the cPanel account from one server to another.

Comment: Thanks Bodgan.  I found the utility as you described.

Comment: It seems that migration would fail if you don't point the name servers to the new VPS.  I want to make sure everything correct before pointing the name servers.  Is that possible?.  Thanks again.